# Using Firebase Hosting + Cloud Run. Should I set `compression()` on my express server?

Tags: firebase, express, gzip, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have a SPA (sing page app) built with React + Firebase.

This is the flow:

**firebase.json**

- Rewrites **everything** to my cloud run `express` server.
- I have a connected custom domain on my Firebase Hosting: `www.example.com`

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "run": {
      "serviceId": "server",
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  }
],
```

In Firebase Hosting [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting), we can see that Firebase Hosting serves content over the CDN with `gzip` enabled by default.

[image]

Given that fact, does it make send to turn `on` the compression on my `express` server over on Cloud Run?

Example:

```
const app = express();      // INITIALIZE EXPRESS APP

const publicFolder = path.resolve(__dirname,"../public");

app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(publicFolder));
```

I'm guessing that it makes sense, because Firebase Hosting compresses the data from the `Hosting CDN to users`, and my `express` server will compress data from `Cloud Run to Hosting CDN`, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

From what the doc is saying, static content are automatically cached on the CDN and served with right compression to your users. However by default, requests handled by backend code (Cloud Functions or Cloud Run) do not cache on the CDN due to its dynamic nature.

Instead of setting compression through your app, configure caching of dynamic content by setting up `Cache-Control`  and marking the cache as `public`. Once the backend content is cached, then Firebase Hosting will compress it depending on what the user can handle (gzip or Brotli).

For example:

```
res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');
```

> **Note:** Only GET and HEAD requests can be cached. HTTPS requests using other methods are never cached.

---

See more at https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache.

Comment: You mean if I'm not getting cached by CDN, I won't have the CDN compression? But the "uncacheable" responses also pass through the CDN don't they?

Comment: That's how CDN works, by storing and delivering cached content to your users. Other CDNs do not compress responses automatically but then, you can serve responses that are compressed by using encodings such as gzip. If your responses are uncacheable due to the type of request you've sent, then it would make sense that you configure compression and other optimizations through your backend code.